# Filter DIVs with cards inside

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need to filter DIVs with cards inside by their categories.
In my issue it works only with letters. I think problem is in Javascript, but I cant see it.
Do you know what it is?

I created 5 buttons with exact categories 'a', 'b' 'c' etc.
If I want to show only category 'A', I'll use data-cat="a" in div.
If inside div is only one letter, it work fine, but If I put div with cards and images inside and tag them as data-cat="a", their visibility is changing to "none". So, if I press button to filter category A I can see only letters without a card inside it. If you don't understand what I mean try **Live Preview:** http://filter.8u.cz

I want to see shopping card when I click on exact category.

```html
<!--This one works--> 
<div class="portfolio-item" data-cat="a">A</div>
```

If I put another div with card inside, it's not visible.

```js
var Portfolio = {
    sort: function (items) {
        Portfolio.hideAll($('#portfolio-content *'));
        Portfolio.showAll(items);
    },
    showAll: function (items) {
        items.fadeIn(700);
    },
    hideAll: function (items) {
        items.hide();
    },
    doSort: function () {
        $('div', '.button-group').on('click', function () {
            var $a = $(this);
            if (!$a.is('#all')) {
                var items = $('div[data-cat=' + $a.data('cat') + ']', '#portfolio-content');
                Portfolio.sort(items);
            } else {
                var items = $('#portfolio-content *');
                Portfolio.hideAll(items);
                Portfolio.showAll(items);
            }
        });
    }
};

Portfolio.doSort();
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Expected output is my shopping card on output when I click on exact category. <div class="portfolio-item" data-cat="a">A<!--This one works-->  </div> When I put another div with card inside, it's not visible. Try it in Live Preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `$("#portfolio-content *")` to `$("#portfolio-content .portfolio-item")`.

With `*`, you are referencing EVERY child element, no matter if it is an image, span or anything else.

By referencing `.portfolio-item`, you will only hide the wrappers, instead of hiding its children.